# Ramchal and Tzimtzum

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, ramchal

[Tzimtzum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzimtzum) is a term said to be used in the teaching of Isaac Luria. It claims that God began the process of creation by "contracting" his infinite light in order to allow for a "conceptual space" in which finite and seemingly independent realms could exist. (Note that many interpretations of what the Tzimtzum is exists. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/718/2699))

Where, if he did at all, does the Ramchal give his interpretation of the Tzimtzum? I've come up empty with a Google Search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **ספר הכללים** which can be found in the back of most editions of דעת תבונות (and is the "basis" of Daas Tevunos), in siman ב, the Ramchal writes:

> הצמצום הוא מה שהאדון ב"ה כבש כביכול חוק טובו בבריאת נבראיו, שלא לעשותם שלימים אפילו לפי ערכם, כל שכן לפי ערכו

Roughly translated:
"Tzimtzum is that which Hashem restricted the nature of His complete goodness in creating creations, to make them incomplete, not only according to Hashem's completeness, but even in their own level of completeness"

In the corresponding discussion in Da'as Tevunos siman כו, he explains this further:

> שהאלוק ב"ה היה יכול ודאי לברוא האדם וכל הבריאה בתכלית השלימות. א
>   ולא עוד, אלא שמחוקו היה ראוי שיהיה כך, כי להיותו שלם בכל מיני שלימות - גם פעולותיו ראוי שתהיינה שלימות כבל שלימות. אלא שכאשר גזרה חכמתו להניח לאדם שישלים הוא את עצמו, ברא הבריות האלה חסרות השלימות. **והרי זה כאילו עכב מדת שלימותו וטובו הגדול שלא לעשות כחק גדולתה בבריות האלה, אלא לעשותם האותה התכונה שרצה בה** לפי התכלית המכוון במחשבתו הנשגבת

(I bolded the part which most succinctly expresses it)

Hashem really could have, and *should have*, created complete beings, as He is perfect and the nature of perfection is to produce perfection.  He "limited" Himself to complete imperfection, and it is *as if* He held back the degree of His perfection to create imperfection.

Answer (score 4):

I think the passage YEZ quoted is the best passage.

For additional material, the [entry צמצום](http://www.aspaklaria.info/090_TSADI/%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9D.htm) in the encyclopedia [אספקלריא](http://www.aspaklaria.info/) collects several more passages from the writings of the Ramhal on the topic.

There are different aspects to the Tzimtzum for the Ramhal: there is the aspect of our existence not being perfect, as related in that passage quoted by YEZ; there is also an aspect of God choosing to act in a way that would allow the contemplation of human beings, rather than in a way that would be infinitely beyond us. Here is one passage from the encyclopedia entry (from the Ramhal's work [מלחמות משה](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/luzzato/kelalej_milchamot_mose.htm)) that discusses that aspect of the Ramhal's interpretation of Tzimtzum:

> ראשית הכל הוא לדעת שבין בבריאת העולם בין בהנהגת הקב"ה לא פעל בדרך כל
>   יכול, כמו שהוא באמת, אלא בדרך בני אדם שעושים הדברים מעט מעט, כן כל
>   המציאות עשאה ועושה אותה בהדרגה זאת. שאם היה פועל בדרך כל יכולתו לא
>   היינו יכולים לדבר כלום במעשיו, כי לא היתה לנו הבנה כלל בהם, ומפני שפעל
>   בהדרגה יש לנו מקום להתבונן בהם.
>
> וזהו הצמצום שאמרנו, שצמצם אין סוף את אורו, שלא רצה להכנס בענין בריאת
>   העולם בכל יכולתו אלא בדרך משוער, כי שתי דרכים למחשבה העליונה, דרך כל
>   יכולתו ודרך ההדרגה, והנה קודם שברא העולם לא היה צורך בדרך ההדרגה, אלא
>   כשרצה לברא העולם אז היה זמן שיתחלק הדרך הזה, ונמצא, שלא רצה שכל יכולתו
>   יכנס בבריאת העולם, אלא דרך הדרגה, הרי שצמצם כל יכולתו, שלא ליכנס בענין
>   זה, וקבע דרך ההדרגה, וחלקי הדרך הזה ומשפטיו הוא מה שאנו מבינים.
>
> הענין הזה במלים הידועות בין חכמי האמת, לכל יכולתו אנו קוראים אין סוף
>   ב"ה, דהיינו הרצון העליון בשלמותו, ולדרך ההדרגה אנו קוראים ספירות,
>   נמצא, שהמאציל ית"ש שהוא המצוי הראשון, צמצם את רצונו הכל יכול, וקבע דרך
>   ההדרגה, ולפיכך אנחנו אומרים שהאין סוף נתצמצם, ואז נגלו הספירות, מכאן
>   והלאה נדבר בספירות ובהדרגותיהם
>
> The first thing to know is that—whether in creating the world, whether
>   in guiding it—the Holy One did not act in the manner of omnipotence (which
>   would have been appropriate to his true nature) but rather in the
>   manner of human beings who do things bit by bit. So, He made and does
>   make all existence in this step-by-step way. For if he were to act in
>   the manner of his omnipotence, we would be unable to speak of his acts
>   at all, for we would have no understanding of them at all; but because
>   he acted step-by-step, we have an entry into the contemplation of them.
>
> And this is the Tzimtzum that we mentioned, that the There-Is-No-End
>   limited His light, for He did not want to enter into the matter of the
>   creation of the world in His omnipotence but rather in a measured way.
>   For the supernal thought has two ways, the way of His omnipotence and
>   the way of step-by-step. Before He created the world there was no need
>   for the way of step-by-step, but when He desired to create the world,
>   the time came to distinguish that way. So one finds that He did not
>   want His omnipotence to enter into the creation of the world, but
>   rather the manner of step-by-step; therefore, He limited His omnipotence,
>   so as not to enter in that way into this matter, and set the way of
>   step-by-step. And the parts of this [step-by-step] way, and its laws,
>   are what we understand.
>
> This topic in the vocabulary of the Kabbalists: His omnipotence is
>   referred to as אין סוף ב"ה, i.e., the supernal will in its unlimitedness, and
>   the way of step-by-step is referred to as ספירות. So,
>   the Emanator, the first existent, limited His all-capable will, and
>   set himself the way of gradation; therefore we say that the אין סוף
>   limited itself and the ספירות were revealed; from that point on,
>   we speak of the ספירות and their processes.

Comment: In this the Ramchal follows the Rama miPano, saying צמצם את רצונו there is Ratzon and Baal Haratzon

Comment: I think this is the best passage, you humble person you

Answer (score 1):

The most thorough treatment of tzimtzum in Ramchal that I have seen is in the first several chapters of his 138 gates of wisdom (klach pischei chochma) specifically chapters 24 and 25 (though each chapter builds on the next).

[This blog](http://ramchal.wordpress.com/) goes through each gate in great detail in English.

This is a [good post to start with](http://ramchal.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/how-ari-and-ramchal-depicted-the-tzimtzum/)