# Comparative analysis of Tanya vs. Nefesh HaChaim

Tags: tanya, nefesh-hachaim

Has anyone done a comparative analysis of the Tanya vs. the Nefesh HaChaim in terms of what they agree about and what they disagree about?

Comment: see here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/718/2699

Comment: @Bochur613 That is but one data point.

Comment: may be of interest http://seforim.blogspot.com/2016/02/bridging-kabbalistic-gap-nefesh.html

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2016/06/rabbi-chaim-volozhins-motivation-to.html?m=1